# Key press event not being triggered when I press another key and release. while my previous key remains pressed

Tags: javascript

In my small car game if I press and hold "w" key the car moves forward and when I press "d" key and the "w" key at the same time, the car moves diagonally  but if I release the "d" key. car should keep going forwards but the car stops.

How can I fix this problem?, if I release the "d" key while keeping the "w" key pressed down, the car should go forward.

```
var twokey = {
    d : false,
    r   : false,
    g : false
};

function dig(event){
    if ((event.which+32) === 114){ // r
        twokey.r = true;
    }
    else if((event.which+32) === 100){ // d
        twokey.d = true;
    }
    else if((event.which+32) === 103){ // g
        twokey.g = true;
    }
}

function cod(event){
    unicod = event.charCode;
    console.log(unicod);
}

var eleme = document.getElementById("limit").getBoundingClientRect();
elemen = document.getElementById("limit");
var unicod = 0;
var etop = eleme.top;
var eleft = eleme.left;

function myMove() {
    if(twokey.d && twokey.r){
         elemen.style.top = (etop-=6)+'px';
         elemen.style.left = (eleft-=6)+'px';
    }
    else if(twokey.g && twokey.r){
         elemen.style.top = (etop-=6)+'px';
         elemen.style.left = (eleft+=6)+'px';
    }
    else{
    switch(unicod){
        case 114: // r 
            elemen.style.top = (etop-=6)+'px';
            break;
        case 100:  // d 
            elemen.style.left = (eleft-=6)+'px';
            break;
        case 103: // g 
            elemen.style.left =(eleft+=6)+'px';
            break;
        case 102: // f 
            elemen.style.top = (etop+=6)+'px';  
            break; 
    }
    }
}

function resetob(event){
     if (event.which+32 === 114){ // r
        twokey.r = false;
        console.log("reset r",event.which+32);
    }
    else if(event.which+32 === 100){ // d
        console.log("reset d",event.which+32);
        twokey.d = false;
    }
    else if(event.which+32 === 103){ // g
        console.log("reset g",event.which+32);
        twokey.g = false;
    }
    }
}
 var body = document.getElementById("bo");
body.addEventListener("keypress",cod);
body.addEventListener("keydown",dig);
body.addEventListener("keyup",resetob);
body.addEventListener("keypress",myMove);
```

Comment: It's your `myMove()` function switch. Your variable `unicod` is set in the `cod(event)` function, but you're not adding the 32 like you are everywhere else. What I mean is, all of your cases fail

Comment: sir charCode is not for keyup Or keydown event it is only for keypress event    and which return charector code instead of unicode  so after adding 32 code become unicode.

Comment: My apologies, I missed that part. Your `dig(e)` function `e.which` returns unicode though.